# Injecting dependency to a Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I would like to inject a singleton object dependency to a Spring bean. The catch is that I can't access and modify the class whose object I want to be injected. Let me describe on the example.

So I have my interface, and the implementation of this interface, like the following.

```
public interface MyServiceProxy {

    String BEAN_NAME = "MyServiceProxy";

    Data getData(String dataId);
}


public class MyServiceProxyImpl implements MyServiceProxy {

    private final MyServiceClient client;

    public MyServiceProxyImpl(MyServiceClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public Data getData(String dataId) {//...}
```

Then in my Configuration class, I am creating a bean, but I need to pass it the `MyServiceClient` object in the constructor, and the catch is that I can't make `MyServiceClient` a bean because it's from external package and I can't modify it.

```
@Configuration
public class MyServiceProxyConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = MyServiceProxy.BEAN_NAME)
    public MyServiceProxy getMyServiceProxy(MyServiceClient client) { // could not autowire client
        return new MyServiceProxyImpl(client);
    }
}
```

So what I would like to do, is being able to pass/autowire an argument to `getMyServiceProxy` bean. Currently IntelliJ is giving me an error *Could not autowire client*. How can this be achieved?

**UPDATE**

Would something like the following work? Because IntelliJ is still reporting an "could not autowire" error. So if I created a bean method that returns the `client` I want injected, and then add @Inject annotation to the method where I want it injected.

```
public class MyServiceClientBuilder {

    private final ClientBuilder builder;

    public MyServiceClientBuilder(ClientBuilder builder) {
        this.builder = builder;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyServiceClient build() {
        return builder.newClient();
    }


@Configuration
public class MyServiceProxyConfiguration {

    @Inject
    @Bean(name = MyServiceProxy.BEAN_NAME)
    public MyServiceProxy getMyServiceProxy(MyServiceClient client) { // could not autowire client
        return new MyServiceProxyImpl(client);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about removing the argument from the method, and using `return new MyServiceProxyImpl(MyServiceClient.getInstance())`?

Comment: In your updated code, `MyServiceClient` would not get created as a Bean because MyServiceClientBuilder does not have annotation and Spring will just ignore that `@Bean` annotation in `MyServiceClientBuilder`. But something similar is done in my answer, have you checked it?

Comment: @BojanTrajkovski Hi, yes, I have, I think you are right. I am going to try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `MyServiceClient` as a separate bean in your configuration file like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyServiceProxyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyServiceClient getMyServiceClient () { 
        return MyServiceClient.getInstance(); //initiate MyServiceClient
    }

    @Bean(name = MyServiceProxy.BEAN_NAME)
    public MyServiceProxy getMyServiceProxy(MyServiceClient client) { 
         return new MyServiceProxyImpl(client);
    }
}
```

I have not tested this code, but it should work.