# Best practice of injecting a non bean property

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a object which i would like to convert to a spring singleton, which contains a property i would like to inject after its initialization. The property cannot be initiated as a bean and I would like it to be retrieved from the code.

```
public class BigObject{
    private SmallObject prop;
}
```

I added the following bean:

```
<bean id="BigObject" class="com.cisco.cpm.lsd.SessionPublisher"
      scope="singleton" init-method="init"  destroy-method="destroy" lazy-init="true">                
</bean>
```

Is there a best practice way of initilizing `prop`?
I know this can be done via a property factory method

```
<property name="prop">
    <bean factory-bean="SmallObjectFactory" factory-method="getSmallObject"></bean>
</property>
```

But that requires me to add a new object just for that property initilization. Is there a better solution?

Comment: If `BigObject` is a spring singleton, then you can use `@PostConstruct` annotation to initialise its properties. You can check this article; https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Injecting dependency to a Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391028/injecting-dependency-to-a-spring-bean)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly something like this should work. First create a @Configuration that exposes your SmallObject bean:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class YourConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SmallObject getSmallObject() {
        // create a new SmallObject
        return new SmallObject();
    }
}
```

Then, in the BigObject where you want your SmallObject injected you can do something like this:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Component
public class BigObject {
    private SmallObject smallObject;

    @Autowired
    public BigObject(SmallObject smallObject) {
        this.smallObject = smallObject;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!